# Transforming CXF SOAP web-service into a custom HTTP / JSON web-service

Tags: java, json, soap, cxf, stax

I have created a SOAP web-service, running in a tomcat container, using CXF and a WSDL contract approach. The Java code was generated from the WSDL using the maven plugin "cxf-codegen-plugin".

Now, I would like to also expose the web-service as a custom HTTP / JSON web-service by mapping the XML data into JSON data. But I haven't been successful yet and I would appreciate any help to achieve that.

I found that old documentation https://cxf.apache.org/docs/json-support.html on CXF's website (which has also been recently duplicated and not corrected here  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JSON+Support). I got it running with a small fix : `sf.setBindingId(HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING);` instead of `sf.setBindingId(HttpBindingFactory.HTTP_BINDING_ID);` since HttpBindingFactory does not exist anymore in CXF 3.x versions.

The first issue with that solution is that it depends on [jettison-json](https://github.com/jettison-json/jettison) whose last release was published in July 2016. The project looks dead. I could not find any suitable replacement. I only found [StAXON](https://github.com/beckchr/staxon) which is worst : last release in February 2014.
Is there any other library that is well maintained and that implements StAX ?

The second issue is that the example uses a server bean while I already have a container. For the SOAP service, I simply use the `public static Endpoint publish(String address, Object implementor)` function.
How can I use both the Tomcat container and the JSON/XML conversion ?

The third issue is that I could not send a valid JSON request so far. The absence of documentation does not help. Still, I managed to get as far as sending a valid JSON equivalent of the SOAP header content. But I could not manage to guess how to make CXF also reads the equivalent of the SOAP body. The Java interface of the web-service is `public Response get(Header header, Body body);` and I keep getting errors : `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: wrong number of arguments while invoking public abstract Response ServicePort.get(Header,Body) with params [Header@88f6973[user=bbcc2545-27ea-43cd-a1fe-c4a194258e0f]].` Obviously the body is missing.
Is there anyone who knows the right JSON syntax to send a request to a CXF HTTP / JSON web-service that relies on jettison-json ? (Or where could one find a comprehensive documentation ?)

Comment: REST and SOAP are so fundamentally different that converting between the two is really messy. Maybe use the SOAP classes as a starting point but I would not pursue this route. I know people think REST is kind of like SOAP V2 only better but this is not correct. You can run both REST and SOAP together but why on earth would you. SOAP is more service and operations oriented while REST is resource using HTTP verbs as operations.

Comment: I would run both because a lot of people feel more comfortable using REST/JSON than SOAP; would it be only to call the services from Javascript code. It is only a matter of letting the users choose what is best for them. But I do not want to go through the burden of rewriting evrything, I want to capitalize on the existing SOAP service. And the real contract will remain on the WSDL definitions.

Comment: I agree with you but like I said Rest and SOAP cannot be compared directly. They differ so take a  step back instead of trying to fir a SOAP peg into a REST hole.

Comment: You are right. And in fact I do not absolutely need a REST service. What matters is just being able to replace the XML with JSON. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: If you may considere your generated java source code, a your new reference, then I have a solution I can post. This solution will generate wsdl & rest & activemq service.

Comment: No, generating REST service from Java source is not the goal here (and is also well-documented anyway).